# How can I show code (specifically C++) in an HTML page?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

How can I show code in a website using HTML? Basically, I have a C++ program that I'd like to share on my website and I want to show it in the page.

Is there anyway to show a C++ code in HTML other than using HTML text?

Comment: explain... do you want syntax highlighting?  or what?

Comment: If you use Doxygen, you can have functions link to each other

Answer (score 12):

HTML includes [a tag called `<code>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element), which is meant for the purpose you describe.

The spec even includes an example class name convention to indicate which language the code is in:

```
<pre><code class="language-pascal">var i: Integer;
    begin
        i := 1;
    end.</code></pre>
```

I don’t know of any web browser that supports such a convention (come on, Chrome), but the JavaScript syntax highlighters mentioned in other answers could use it to work their magic.

As you can see in the example, the `<code>` tag is usually wrapped in the `<pre>` tag, which preserves white space, which is often important for code.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). It will unobtrusively enhance code samples on your page with specific syntax highlighting for a wide range of languages.

Here's an example for C++

```
<head>
  <link href="css/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <pre class='brush: cpp'>
  // my first program in C++
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main ()
  {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
  }
  </pre>

  <script src="js/shCore.js"></script>
  <script src="js/shBrushCpp.js"></script>
  <script>
    SyntaxHighlighter.all()
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems a shame to put code in an HTML page without using the `<code>` tag.

Answer (score 9):

There are various syntax highlighters out there.  [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) is a pretty good one.  (Good enough for Stack Overflow to use, anyway.)